# form value is empty

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a UI and below is my basic getting input from forms, but it won't display the value of secondLetter if I do it like

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
let firstLetter = document.querySelector('#firstLetter').value;
let secondLetter = document.querySelector('#secondLetter').value;
const output = document.querySelector('#check');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(secondLetter);
})
```

But If do it like

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
let firstLetter = document.querySelector('#firstLetter').value;
let secondLetter = document.querySelector('#secondLetter');
const output = document.querySelector('#check');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(form.secondLetter.value);
})
```

I get the value. I don't understand what I am doing wrong or why second example work and not first. Following is my HTML for reproducing purpose

```
    <form id="form">
    <label for="firstLetter">First Letter</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstLetter">
    <label for="secondLetter">Second Letter</label>
        <input type="text" id="secondLetter">
    <input type="submit" id="check">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st code runs when the page loads (your form laod):

```
let secondLetter = document.querySelector('#secondLetter').value;
```

so secondLetter will be set to value "" ,  even when your form will be submited the varable **is already se**t so you will get "".

AT the 2nd code:  you set secondLetter to the element reference, and only on submit you give the value to secondLetter, not before the submit.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" id="secondLetter">` doesn't have a `value` attribute, so `document.querySelector('#secondLetter').value` is going to be an empty string.

(If you wanted to type something into the input and **then** read the value, then your JS would need to wait until something had been typed … you would normally use an Event Listener for that).

Comment: but I asking for a value on Event Listener of submit.

Comment: @Nofel — No. You ask for the value **outside** of that event listener and assign it to a variable. Later on you read the value of that variable.